# Can a docker image use hadoop?

Tags: docker, hadoop, h2o, hdp

Can a docker image access hadoop resources? Eg. submit YARN jobs and access HDFS; something like [MapR's Datasci. Refinery](https://mapr.com/products/data-science-refinery/), but for Hortonworks HDP 3.1. (May assume that the image will be launched on a hadoop cluster node).

Saw the hadoop [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/DockerContainers.html) for launching docker applications from hadoop nodes, but was interested in whether could go the "other way" (ie. being able to start a docker image with the conventional `docker -ti ...` command and have that application be able to run hadoop jars etc. (assuming that the docker image host is a hadoop node itself)). I understand that MapR hadoop has docker images for doing [this](https://mapr.com/products/data-science-refinery/), but am interested in using Hortonworks HDP 3.1. Ultimately trying to run [h2o](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-yau/3/index.html#quickstart-hadoop) hadoop in a docker container.

Anyone know if this is possible or can confirm that this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  As long as you have the client jars and appropriate configs similar to an edge node for your container it should work.

Comment: I see, thanks. For others finding this post, found links here (https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-operating-system/content/run_docker_containers_on_yarn.html) and here (https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-operating-system/content/recommendations_for_running_docker_containers_on_yarn.html) that may be helpful for further understanding.